# R can not be resolved while using MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, eclipse-plugin

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MoschipActivitysec.this, R.raw.button);

here button is  a .mp3 audio file which resides in raw folder in res,getting R is not resolved!

Comment: first try cleaning your project, if not work then update your question with your AndroidManifest.xml file's code

Comment: you should place the sound files in raw folder or assets folder.

Comment: thnx it works after renaming of sounds folder into raw

Answer (score 0):

Two things might be causing this.

Firstly have a look at the imports section of your class. Sometimes eclipse imports a different `R` file, which causes that error. If there's anything in the imports which imports a random `R` file then delete that line.

Otherwise it could be that the `R` file hasn't been created properly, sometimes a clean and rebuild fixes, other times I've had to delete the `R` file completely and rebuild.

If neither of these fix it then let us know.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import R file. 1st Clean and build your project. On you java file

```
import your.project.package.R;
```

Please not you have to write to package name of your project. e.g `com.my.abc`

Alternatively you can call "Organize Imports" by pressing **Ctrl + Shif + O** or by Right clicking on your project then "Source -> Organize Imports"

Please note: R.sounds.button is not valid.